# Url launcher exception in iOS when subject OR body is in Chinese language

Tags: flutter, dart

Below code working in android device but in iOS device it's throw an exception

```
dynamic _sendEmail() async {
    String url = 'mailto:support@test.com?subject=请写以上这个线';
    if (await canLaunch(url)) {
      await launch(url);
    } else {
      throw 'Could not launch $url';
    }
  }
```

```
Could not launch mailto:support@k8sllc.com?subject=请写以上这个线
```

Comment: Did you solve this problem? I am facing the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

You should encode your url:

```dart
String url = Uri.encodeComponent('mailto:support@test.com?subject=请写以上这个线');
```

so it looks like this:

```
mailto%3Asupport%40test.com%3Fsubject%3D%E8%AF%B7%E5%86%99%E4%BB%A5%E4%B8%8A%E8%BF%99%E4%B8%AA%E7%BA%BF
```

Comment: I tried but it's not working on both android and iOS devices.